# Timing loops with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is it possible to get the execution time of a loop with an asynchronous function inside of the loop?

The following would work for synchronous functions, but not asynchronous:

```
var amount = 100; 
var start = new Date().getTime();

for(var i=0; i < amount; i++){
 // function 
}

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = (end - start) / 1000;
```

If so, how can I convert the above code so that `time` holds the value of the total time the loop (and the function inside) takes to run?

Comment: Sounds like the *loop* is pretty irrelevant, and you actually want to profile your asynchronous function...!?

Comment: Nope, I want to get the time it takes to run the asynchronous function X times. where X is a fairly large number (1000's of times).

Comment: Do you need to wait for the function to finish before you fire it again in your test, or just wait for all invocations to finish - ie should the async functions be fired serially or in parallel?

Comment: Parallel, I don't need to wait for one to finish for the next to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something like this;

```
var amount = 100; 
var completionAmount = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime();
var end, time;
var theFunction = function(){
    // bla bla
}
var calbackOfTheFunction = function(){
    //bla bla
    completionAmount++;
    if(completionAmount === 100){
        end = new Date().getTime();
        time = (end - start) / 1000;
    }
};


for(var i=0; i < amount; i++){
    theFunction(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Instead of using `completionAmount` could I not just use `amount - 1` inside the `if(...)` statement? e.g. `if(i === (amount -1)) { .. }`?

Comment: in this example `calbackOfTheFunction` does not have `i`. if you pass `calbackOfTheFunction` to `theFunction` inside for loop, you can pass `i` as well of course.

Comment: And even if you had `i`, it may yield wrong results to use `i` since `i=98` may be the last calback fired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
async.parallel(arrayOfAsyncFunctions, function() {
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = (end - start) / 1000;
});
```

Once all async functions have completed, the callback will be called.

Also, you can use any other promise libraries, for example [q.all](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or write your own code to emulate this behavior.

Comment: I've looked at that, but the problem is I'd need to run the async function a large amount of times, hence the for loop. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Of course, in such case look at the @yılmaz answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630006/timing-loops-with-asynchronous-functions/34630198#34630198

Answer (score 1):

If the async operation can accept a callback parameter, you can put the calculation in the callback:

```
var time;
for(var i=0; i < amount; i++){
   asyncfunction(someParam, anotherParam, function () {
      var end = new Date().getTime();
      time = (end - start) / 1000;
      // do stuff with time
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it would fire for each call of the function, so it would time each call individually, not all of them, wouldn't it?

Comment: As long as `start` does not change, `end - start` will give you the whole time period.