# Wait for Node.js express app calling http.request's in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, express

My head's about to explode. Please know that I waited about a week before posting this. The shame alone of not being able to figure this out mixed with the sheer amount of personal time wasted puts me in a very dark place. I ask you interwebs... please show me the way.

I am writing my first NodeJS Express 4 app that will manage my home automation system (which has a Rest API). The thing that kills me is I have 99% of the code done, I just can not get it to wait for the looping http.request's to finish before calling my return callback out of the function below.

I have tried, DeAsync, Async, wait.for,... I just can't seem to get it mainly because of being in a for loop. Anyone who can help sort this out for me. I just can't get my head around async or callbacks well enough to nail this down.

The main thing is it takes in a object with name:value pairs, then loops them, calls a web service, stuff an object I am calling: ISYGetData, then finally should fire the main callback which would then trigger another function to render a web page template with the data in the response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function runISYGet(runISYGetInput, resInput, runISYGetCallback) {
//console.dir(runISYGetInput);
//console.log('length:' + runISYGetInput.length);
ISYGetData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < runISYGetInput.length; i++) {
    // runISYGetInput Object Example: 
    // runISYGetInput = [
    //  { id: "36981", operation: "on" }
    //  , { id: "82563", operation: "on" }
    //  , { id: "52839", operation: "on" }
    //  , { id: "17383", operation: "on" }
    //  , { id: "38863", operation: "on" }  

    console.log('Starting Loop: ISYGet with %s,%s', runISYGetInput[i].id, runISYGetInput[i].operation);

    if (runISYGetInput[i].operation.toUpperCase() == "ON") {
        var operationTranslated = "DON"
    } else {
        var operationTranslated = "DOF"
    }

    if (typeof runISYGetInput[i].intensity === 'undefined') {
        console.log('Nothing in intensity');
    };

    var options = {
        hostname: hostname
        ,port: port
        ,path: "/rest/nodes/" + runISYGetInput[i].id + "/cmd/" + operationTranslated + "/"
        ,method: 'GET'
        ,auth: username + ':' + password
    }

    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log("Inside httpGet | Calling ISY Now");
        //console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        //console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);

            if (i == 0) {
                ISYGetData = [{
                        hostname: options.hostname
                        ,port: options.port
                        ,path: options.path
                        ,statusCode: res.statusCode
                        ,responseHeaders: JSON.stringify(res.headers)
                        ,body: chunk.toString('utf8')
                }]
            } else {
                ISYGetData = ISYGetData.concat([{
                        hostname: options.hostname
                        ,port: options.port
                        ,path: options.path
                        ,statusCode: res.statusCode
                        ,responseHeaders: JSON.stringify(res.headers)
                        ,body: chunk.toString('utf8')
                }])
            };
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });

    });
    req.end();
}

console.log('This should happen last but doesnt currently, want to run runISYGetCallback(ISYGetData, resInput) after http gets are done and ISYGetData is populated');
// This callback renders the page with all needed data from the ISYGetData object
runISYGetCallback(ISYGetData, resInput);
```

}

Comment: Since http.request is async, node will put the job in the event loop and move on to the next iteration. It doesn't wait for the request to complete. From your question, you want to wait for these async functions to complete before calling the final callback. I would look into using a control flow library like bluebird Promises or Async.js. These libraries enable you to wait for asynchronous functions to complete before moving on to the next iteration.

Comment: Don't launch all your calls at once in a `for` loop. Launch only the first call (in a function), then, in the callback, call the same function again. So, in the second callback, it will then call itself again, and so on. That's recursivity.

Comment: Not sure if this question will help - It's to do with timing, but I the concept is the same, doing something after a set of async functions are done running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630006/timing-loops-with-asynchronous-functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that creates a promise for each `https.request()` operation and then uses `Promise.all()` to wait for all those promises to be done and lets the promise infrastructure gather all the data for you automatically into an array that is in the same order as it was requested.

```
function runISYGet(runISYGetInput, resInput, runISYGetCallback) {
    var operationTranslated, promises = [], options;
    for (var i = 0; i < runISYGetInput.length; i++) {
        if (runISYGetInput[i].operation.toUpperCase() == "ON") {
            operationTranslated = "DON";
        } else {
            operationTranslated = "DOF";
        }
        if (typeof runISYGetInput[i].intensity === 'undefined') {
            console.log('Nothing in intensity');
        }
        // create new options object for each cycle through the loop
        options = {
            hostname: hostname,
            port: port,
            path: "/rest/nodes/" + runISYGetInput[i].id + "/cmd/" + operationTranslated + "/",
            method: 'GET',
            auth: username + ':' + password
        };

        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // save options locally because it will be reassigned to a different object
            // before it gets used in the callback below
            var localOptions = options;
            var req = https.request(localOptions, function (res) {
                var data = "";
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function() {
                    // resolve with the accumulated data
                    // do it this way so that the promise infrastructure will order it for us
                    resolve({
                        hostname: localOptions.hostname,
                        port: localOptions.port,
                        path: localOptions.path,
                        statusCode: res.statusCode,
                        responseHeaders: JSON.stringify(res.headers),
                        body: data.toString('utf8')
                    });
                });
            });
            req.on('error', function (e) {
                console.error(e);
                reject(e);
            });
            req.end();
        }));
    }
    // now wait for all promises to be done
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(allData) {
        // This callback renders the page with all needed data 
        //   when all the https.request() calls are done
        runISYGetCallback(allData, resInput);        
    }, function(err) {
        // figure out what to do here when there was an error in one or more of the https.request() calls
    });
}
```

Note: You could simplify this even more if you use the request-promise module that promisifies the request module for you, but I chose to show an implementation that did not rely on any new modules

**Partial list of things changed:**

1. Create a new promise for each request in the loop
2. Wait for all promises to be done using `Promise.all()`
3. Capture options object separately for each pass through the loop so the options object we're using won't be overwritten by the next cycle through the loop during async processing
4. Let promises capture all the results so they will put them in the proper order (rather than concatenating them as they arrive)
5. Collect all chunks of data that arrive for each request into one piece (since data can arrive in multiple chunks)
6. Trigger completion of the promise based on `res.on('end')` which you were not using
7. Move `req.on('error')` up to a higher level where it belongs
8. Use promise rejection upon request error to propagate errors back to the highest level
9. Move declaration of local variables outside the `for` loop.

---

FYI, you might want to replace the runISYGetCallback with a promise too by just returning the promise from the runISYGet function like this:

```
function runISYGet(runISYGetInput, runISYGetCallback) {
    var operationTranslated, promises = [], options;
    for (var i = 0; i < runISYGetInput.length; i++) {
        if (runISYGetInput[i].operation.toUpperCase() == "ON") {
            operationTranslated = "DON";
        } else {
            operationTranslated = "DOF";
        }
        if (typeof runISYGetInput[i].intensity === 'undefined') {
            console.log('Nothing in intensity');
        }
        // create new options object for each cycle through the loop
        options = {
            hostname: hostname,
            port: port,
            path: "/rest/nodes/" + runISYGetInput[i].id + "/cmd/" + operationTranslated + "/",
            method: 'GET',
            auth: username + ':' + password
        };

        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // save options locally because it will be reassigned to a different object
            // before it gets used in the callback below
            var localOptions = options;
            var req = https.request(localOptions, function (res) {
                var data = "";
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function() {
                    // resolve with the accumulated data
                    // do it this way so that the promise infrastructure will order it for us
                    resolve({
                        hostname: localOptions.hostname,
                        port: localOptions.port,
                        path: localOptions.path,
                        statusCode: res.statusCode,
                        responseHeaders: JSON.stringify(res.headers),
                        body: data.toString('utf8')
                    });
                });
            });
            req.on('error', function (e) {
                console.error(e);
                reject(e);
            });
            req.end();
        }));
    }
    // return master promise that is resolved when all the other promises are done
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

// usage
runISYGet(...).then(function(allData) {
    // process the data here
}, function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough for taking the time to both answer and explain. Still absorbing it a bit but this is huge help to get me to that "ah ha" moment I have been struggling to get to with node/js/async. Thanks again

Comment: @EricWeintraub - I added a refined version that replaces the `runISYGetCallback` with a returned promise.